# How can I get started with using WF 4.0 in typical web site scenarios?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, workflow

I have developed for SharePoint and in those cases it is clear how workflow can help (You have documents that needs approval and there are built in SharePoint workflows for this)

But now I am doing standard ASP.NET web CRUD apps with WCF. I would like to find a way to get WF 4.0 involved but I am not sure how to do it and never see any examples.

Can anyone give me some basic scenarios that I could use WF for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use WF for a web site in most of the cases. A monolithic web app is a lot faster to develop and performs better. WF is useful if your app becomes very complex, you have many many developers. Than you can move to a an WF to manage complexity and enable multiple teams to work simultaneously. You put your business logic that changes most often in workflows them self and build stable services that the workflows calls.

BTW you've put WCF tag instead of WF.

Comment: I know its overkill in alot of cases.. But I was just looking for a excuse to use it so I could get familiar with it.. 

I understand how it works with sharepoint.. but I can't find any basic ways to use it outside of sharepoint.. 

you can use th elogic diagram to represent a line of logic in code but that seems a total waste.. 

So I am trying to understand what it means to hold a state of something over a long time and how that works with WF that is NOT a SP site.. .

Answer (score 0):

For some videos of how you can use workflow in sharepoint see: http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/04/series-of-sharepoint-workflow-how-to-videos.aspx

Note: Workflow in sharepoint 2007 and 2010 is based on .net 3.5

**EDIT**

A good place to start is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx

Comment: I know how to use WF in Sharepoint... But now I am doing non Sharepoint websites.. So my question is how to use WF in non SP sites.. or some examples?